# No option in a dynamic dependant drop-down list after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So, I have a form which includes two drop-down lists: `id="dd-1"` & `id="dd-2"`.

The `id="dd-2"` options created from the database based on the `id="dd-1"` selection; I am using the `onChange=getChildOf(this.value)` in `id="dd-1"` to do that.

When the user selects an option in `id="dd-1"` I run an ajax function which passes the value of `id="dd-1"` to *another* `PHP` page where it runs a `MySqli` query and then updates the `id="dd-2"`.

Up to here, everything is fine.

**What I need is:**

1. Remember the user selection in `id="dd-1"`. **DONE**
2. Get the `id="dd-2"` options based on the *submitted* value of the `id="dd-1"`. ***not done***

After the form submission the `id="dd-2"` shows no options at all.  So, I have to change the selection in `id="dd-1"` again so the `ajax` getChildOf(val) function gets fired!

### **So, I need your help please in getting #2 done.**

---

**FYI:**

The `id="dd-1"` select drop-down list looks smothing like:

```
<select id="dd-1" name="dd-1" onChange="getChildOf(this.value)">
    <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['dd-1'])&&$_POST['dd-1']=='1'){echo 'selected';}?> >Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['dd-1'])&&$_POST['dd-1']=='2'){echo 'selected';}?> >Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['dd-1'])&&$_POST['dd-1']=='3'){echo 'selected';}?> >Option 3</option>
</select>
```

---

The `id="dd-2"` select drop-down list looks smothing like:

```
<select id="dd-2" name="dd-2"></select>
```

---

The `ajax` function:

```
function getChildOf(val)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_dd2_options.php",
        data: 'parentid='+val,
        success: function(data){

            $("#dd-2").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

---

The `get_dd2_options.php` page looks smothing like:

```
<html>
<option value="-1">Please Select</option>
<?php
include_once('config.php');

// list all children
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".$_POST['parentid']."'");

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $id     = $r['id'];
    $name   = $r['name'];

    ?> <option value="<?=$id;?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['dd-2'])&&$_POST['dd-2']==$id){echo 'selected';}?> ><?=$name;?></option> <?php
} 
?>
```

Comment: Are you doing a full form submit or an ajax post?  If it's the former could you not check the value of dd1 and populate dd2 in PHP before showing the form again?

Comment: @Russell I am doing a full form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, I don't know which would be best since I'm not looking at the full code base.

Option 1: After post when you check for dd1 to be set you add another check for dd2 in php.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['dd-1']) {
    /* populate dd-2 based on dd-1 value*/
}
?>
```

Option 2: Add the logic to populate dd2 to page load.